# What are rafters for in resx files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resx

In resx files I see some elements prefixed by 2 rafters like so:

```
  <data name=">>txtSourcePath.Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>txtSourcePath</value>
  </data>
```

What does that mean?

Comment: This question made me curious because I never heard the term “rafter”. I tried looking it up online but couldn’t find anything.

Comment: I think he talks about the two angle brackets within the name property `">>txtSourcePath"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to add such a property through the *Managed Resource Editor* you'll get an error message: "The resource name is not a valid identifier".

But what I found is

```
<data name="&gt;&gt;txtSourcePath.Name" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>txtSourcePath</value>
</data>
```

This is used if you set the "Localizable" property of a form in the property grid to true. In that case a .resx file with the angle brackets will be created and the values will be applied within the Designer.cs file by calling `resources.ApplyResources()`.

So it seems your form uses some kind of localization.